# error when start apache2.4

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I've installed apache2.4 on ubuntu14.04 using this tutorial successfully(from source):
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html
but in step 8 in this tutorial it said that I should edit httpd.conf
but it seems a hard job! without editing this file, I went to step 9 and run this command to start apache:

> /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start

but I see this error:

> /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

is this error about step 8 ? If yes, how should I edit httpd.conf ?
If not, what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: this might help !  http://chandank.com/webservers/nginx/nginx-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpcre-so-1

Comment: This is off-topic as it is about server configuration and not software development. It belongs on [webmasters.se] or [sf]

Comment: http://chandank.com/webservers/nginx/nginx-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpcre-so-1 didn't solve my problem viper.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try this,

- sudo rm /etc/ld.so.cache
- sudo /sbin/ldconfig